# Import a 2gb dump file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, command-line-arguments, wampserver

I couldn't import a 2gb dump into phpmyadmin even after changing the default values in .ini file. How to import 2gb sql file through command line into phpmyadmin. Please help me with this.

Comment: are you using LINUX?

Comment: No, I am using Windows

Comment: can you show what have you return in your .ini file

Comment: I'd think your web server would have something to say -- independently of PHP and myadmin -- about you posting a 2GB request.  It's pretty common to set a much lower limit on request size in order to make it harder for some schmuck to DOS the server.You could probably up the limit, but i wouldn't keep it that way any longer than necessary.

Comment: cant you break the file and upload it ??

Comment: Can you please help me importing with command line

Comment: No i cant break them

Answer (score 0):

Use this way in your command line

```
mysql -u db_username -p db_password < backup_name.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh, this kind of issue is already answered on this post, you can try the same.

[How to Import 1GB .sql file to WAMP/phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264324/how-to-import-1gb-sql-file-to-wamp-phpmyadmin/20264467#20264467)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done all the commands in the php.ini file

- post_max_size = 2048M
- upload_max_filesize = 2048M
- max_execution_time= 5000
- max_input_time = 5000
- memory_limit = 2048M

Leaving out even one of them will cause a problem while importing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with the `mysql.exe` command line tool then the simplest and most unobtrusive solution is to make these changes to your `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file. Then these changes are only going to effect `phpmyadmin` and not your whole server.

Add these PHP config changes just before the `</Directory>` line

```
  ## Allow phpmyadmin to load large backups 
  ## and run for long enough to process the large file

  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 2100M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 2100M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 1200
  php_admin_value max_input_time 1200
</Directory>
```