# How to update database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my database. I have a database which is more than 680MB. When I am trying to import into any database some tables are uploading and some are failing. It shows error,

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array

([type] => 1
[message] => Maximum execution time of 300 seconds e' at line 89)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qNZ8.png)

so how do I upload it successfully?

Comment: And what happens when you upload the file again, as the error suggests you do?

Comment: Also, do you have shell access to your web server? If you can't control the PHP execution time limit, you may be able to import a large file like this via the command line.

Comment: phpmyadmin as all php scripts is restricted by the max script execution time restriction. Either disable the limit, or better: do not use a web-based solution to import 680 MB file into any database. Use some proper clients, that are not restricted by execution times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Import 1GB .sql file to WAMP/phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264324/how-to-import-1gb-sql-file-to-wamp-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that u change `php.ini` settings to import large db., beacause `phpmyadmin` does not allow large db import. so make sure u do following change in php.ini

```
post_max_size= 1700MB // as per req.
upload_max_filesize=1280M // as per req
max_execution_time = 300
```